# Quotient Ring has No Zero Divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring without identity and with no zero divisors. Let $S$ be the ring whose additive group is $R \times \Bbb{Z}$. Let $A = \{(r,n)\in S \mid rx + nx = 0 \text{ for every } x \in R\}$.
>   (a) $A$ is an ideal in $S$.
>   (b) $S/A$ has an identity and contains a subring isomomorphic to $R$.
>   (c) $S/A$ has no zero divisors.

Multiplication on $R \times \Bbb{Z}$ is defined like so: $(r,n) \cdot (s,k) = (rs + kr + ns,nk)$. I was able to prove parts (a) and (b), but I am having trouble with part (c). I could use a hint.

On a somewhat related note (perhaps I might stretch the definition of "related"), to prove that the quotient of a principal ideal ring is a principal ideal ring, wouldn't I just use the fact that $f : R \to R/I$ defined by $f(r) = r + I$ is a surjective ring homomorphism, and so if $R$ is a principal ideal ring, so is $f(R) = R/I$? I asked this in chat but didn't receive any responses; and I didn't think this question merited its own post.

Comment: Is $R$ commutative? Also, in your definition of $A$, do you want the condition to hold for *every* $x\in R$, or just *some* $x\in R$?

Comment: @DavidHill $R$ is not necessarily commutative. Regarding your second question, the condition is in fact that the equation holds for every $x \in R$.

Comment: I guess I'm not worried about commutativity. Zero divisor means two-sided zero divisor, right? I'm still having trouble seeing a proof of (c), though. If $(r,n)\in R\times\mathbb{Z}$ is a zero divisor, then there exists $(s,k)\in R\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that $(r,n)(s,k)=(rs+kr+ns,nk)=(0,0)$. This forces either $n=0$ or $k=0$. If $k=0$, then $rs+ns=0$ *for this particular $s\in R$*, but I don't see how to conclude that $(r,n)\in A$ from here. If $n=0$, take $(s',k')$ such that $(s',k')(r,0)=(0,0)$. Of course, you run into the same problem as before.

Comment: @DavidHill Oh! But we are not trying to show that $S = R \times \Bbb{Z}$ has no zero divisors but rather the quotient ring $S/A$, where $A$ is defined in my post, has no zero divisors. Regarding your question about zero divisors, the answer is yes.

Comment: @user193319 Where did this problem come from?

Comment: Note that $R\simeq (R,0)\subset S$ and $A=\textrm{ann}(R,0)$ is a two-side ideal of $S$.

Comment: @rschwieb It's problem 12 at the end of the Ideal section in Hungerford's Algebra.